# How to speedup logsumexp on large tensor in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have the following operation in python on very large tensors.

```
# p: 10000x1
# T,W: 400x400x10000
# Kp: 400x400
T = np.tile(p, (n, n, 1))
Kp = np.triu(scipy.special.logsumexp(T + W, axis=-1), k=1)
```

I know I can use the GPU and speed things up considerably w/ PyTorch's logsumexp but I'd like to try to optimize the CPU bound version for now.

Comment: Does `W` have any structure? You could save some work by only taking the logsumexp on the upper triangle

Comment: The front face of the tensor is upper diagonal, I've not indexed tensors in this way before.